# Why can't we use . as a parameter in an anonymous function with %>%

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

Can somebody explain to me why the two following instructions have different outputs:

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
ll <- list(a = mtcars, b = mtcars)
# using '.' as a function parameter
llply(ll, function(.) . %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(min = min(mpg)))
# using 'd' as function parameter
llply(ll, function(d) d %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(min = min(mpg)))
```

The former case is apparently not even evaluated (which I figured by misspelling `summarise`: `llply(ll, function(.) . %>% group_by(cyl) %>% sumamrise(min = min(mpg)))` would *not*  throw an error).

So this has all to do with scoping rules and where things are evaluated, but I really want to understand what is going on, and why this happens? I use `.` as an argument in anonymous functions quite often and I was puzzled to see the outcome.

So long story short, why does `.` not work with `%>%`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` ("the dot") has multiple uses, one of which is indeed as an argument. How it's actually interpreted is highly dependent on its context -- and in your context, it's used immediately before a `%>%` forward-pipe operator. `dplyr` takes its forward-pipe operator from `magrittr`, and from the `magrittr` documentation we have the following snippet on what happens when there's a `. %>% somefunction()`:

> When the dot is used as lhs, the result will be a functional sequence, i.e. a function which applies the entire chain of right-hand sides in turn to its input.

So it's almost like an order of operations thing - a `%>%` immediately after the dot would interpret the dot as a part of the functional sequence.

One way to get your `.` understood as an argument instead is to add brackets around it, i.e.

```
llply(ll, function(.) (.) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(min = min(mpg)))
```

For a more thorough explanation of the different uses of `.` and `%>%`, and their interaction with each other, have a look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/magrittr.pdf. The relevant section starts from page 8.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the right documentation, it becomes quite clear now and I think this answer is a bit more explaining the why

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be because of the special use of `.` as a placeholder when using piping. From `?"%>%"`:

> **Using the dot for secondary purposes**
>
> Often, some attribute or property
>   of lhs is desired in the rhs call in addition to the value of lhs
>   itself, e.g. the number of rows or columns. It is perfectly valid to
>   use the dot placeholder several times in the rhs call, but by design
>   the behavior is slightly different when using it inside nested
>   function calls. In particular, if the placeholder is only used in a
>   nested function call, lhs will also be placed as the first argument!
>   The reason for this is that in most use-cases this produces the most
>   readable code. For example, iris %>% subset(1:nrow(.) %% 2 == 0) is
>   equivalent to iris %>% subset(., 1:nrow(.) %% 2 == 0) but slightly
>   more compact. It is possible to overrule this behavior by enclosing
>   the rhs in braces. For example, 1:10 %>% {c(min(.), max(.))} is
>   equivalent to c(min(1:10), max(1:10)).

Comment: Thanks, basically RTFM - could have figured out myself, but I was so puzzled by this behavior that I thought it is a very special case ;)